# convert string column values to numeric and find maximum in those numeric values in R

Tags: r

I have a column called "XYZ" (XYZ is one of the column in my data frame) in data frame and this "XYZ" column is a string type. values of the "XYZ" column is like below

example:

```
   XYZ
new_value_1
new_value_2
new_value_4
new_value_3
```

I have to get the last digit(which is a number) and convert that into number and finds the maximum among those number. After finding maximum number in that column I need to generate a sequence from that maximum number till n rows.

For example from the above "XYZ" every string has digit at the end I have to get the last digit which is number and finds the maximum in those numbers, in this case maximum is 4 after finding maximum I have to mutate id column and id will starts from next number to the maximum number.

output:

```
 XYZ             ID
new_value_1      5
new_value_2      6
new_value_4      7
new_value_3      8
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please make a minimally reproducible input data set using dput. I've recreated the data set for convenience.

Using the `dplyr` package for ease:

```
library(dplyr)
raw_data <- data.frame("XYZ"= c("new_value_1","new_value_2","new_value_3","new_value_4"))

##get the max value
max_value <- max(sapply(raw_data$XYZ, function(x){as.numeric(strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][3])}))

#make the resulting data

final_data <- raw_data %>% mutate(ID = (max_value+1):(max_value+nrow(raw_data)))
```

Let me know if dplyr is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you, I need solution in base R without sapply

Comment: @Hmm You should edit the question with that information.

Comment: @Hmm: sapply is base R?

Comment: I should not split based on "_" becausee there is possibility string can have only one "_" before the digit

Comment: @Hmm you should edit the question to fully explain all the requirements and the various input strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way. It uses a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/QCeHKa/1) to extract the last digit or digits and `seq.int` to create a sequence like the sequence in the question.

```
m <- max(as.integer(sub("^[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+$)", "\\1", df1$XYZ)))
df1$ID <- m + seq.int(nrow(df1))

df1
#          XYZ ID
#1 new_value_1  5
#2 new_value_2  6
#3 new_value_4  7
#4 new_value_3  8
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
   XYZ
new_value_1
new_value_2
new_value_4
new_value_3
", header = TRUE)
```